# How can obtain deviceId in web application for sending push notification?

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, push-api

I am using a web application that receives notificaitons throught push service.

the notifications are going to send throught the FCM. My backend requires deviceId as in android OS. How can send such unique id that make user device or browser specific?

Comment: Do you mean the device token, which is the only thing FCM needs to send a message to the device. If so, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token

Comment: No. for example  at Android devices, for making device specific, developer can obtain the deviceId. I am looking for getting deviceId in a webApplication. Is it possible?

Comment: FCM tokens are globally unique, and thus each device already gets a unique token. If that isn't what you want, the problems seems unrelated to FCM. In that case, a [search for 'javascript get device id'](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+device+id) gives relevant results. There seems to be no direct API for this, but you can generate and store a UUID - although at that point, I'm not sure why you wouldn't use the FCM token.